# Hide part of website on mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile-browser

Im using section tags on my website.

This is the website - http://mk18.web44.net/

How would I hide the section that is called Place an Order on mobile devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
    #order{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked . Is there any way I could also get hide the menu option for that?

Comment: Great. I found that your site is based on bootstrap framework so you can do it even more simple. For example you can add .hidden-phone class on section you want to hide only on iphone. Check bootstrap documentation for more info: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: Hi Stefan! If my answer satisfied you, can you approve it?